# Fight to death Three people C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, logic

Aaron has a 30% chance of hitting
Bob has a 50% chance of hitting 
Charlie has a 100% chance of hitting

Aaron shoots first, then Bob, then Charlie, everyone tries to shoot the person with the best percantage first. Can someone explain why Aaron isn't winning any rounds? Charlie roughly wins 480 times and Bob wins roughly 200 times, however it reports that Aaron wins 0. Aaaron should be winning roughly 150 - 200 times while Bob is a little greater than that.

Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

const double aShot = 30;
const double bShot = 50;
const double cShot = 100;

void start(bool& aAlive, bool& bAlive, bool& cAlive, int& aCount, int& bCount, int& cCount, double result){

// Aaron Shoots at Charlie
    if (aShot >= result){
            cAlive=false;

}
 //Bob Shoots at Charlie
    if (cAlive == false){
            cout<<"Charlie is dead, Bob shot at Aaron"<<endl;
            if (bShot >= result)
            aAlive = false;
}
    else if ((cAlive == true) && (bShot >= result))
            cAlive = false;

//Charlie Shoots at Bob
    if (cAlive == false){
    cout<<"Charlie is dead"<<endl;
}
    else if ((cAlive == true) && (cShot >= result))
            bAlive = false;
//Aaron Shoots at Bob
    if (bAlive == false){
            cout<<"Bob is dead, Aaron shoots at Charlie"<<endl;
            if (aShot >= result)
            cAlive = false;}
    else if ((bAlive == true) && ( aShot >= result))
            bAlive = false;
//Bob Shoots at Aaron
    if (bAlive == false)
    cout<<"Bob is dead"<<endl;
    else if ((bAlive == true) && (bShot >= result))
            aAlive = false;
//Charlie Shoots at Aaron
if (aAlive == false)
    cout<<"Aaron is dead"<<endl;
    else if ((aAlive == true) && (cShot >= result))
            aAlive = false;

if ((aAlive == true) && (bAlive == false) && (cAlive == false))
aCount++;
if ((aAlive == false) && (bAlive == true) && (cAlive == false))
bCount++;
if ((aAlive == false) && (bAlive == false) && (cAlive == true))
cCount++;

}

int main(){
bool aAlive = true, bAlive = true, cAlive = true;
int i, aCount = 0, bCount = 0, cCount = 0;

            cout<<"Welcome to the game"<<endl;
                    srand (time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<=1000; i++){
//Sets random number, or chance they hit their target
                    double result = rand() % 101;
                    cout<<result<<endl;
//Sets all players to alive
             aAlive = true, bAlive = true, cAlive = true;

//Calling The Duel
            start(aAlive, bAlive, cAlive, aCount, bCount, cCount, result);
    }
            cout<<"Aaron won: "<<aCount<<" times"<<endl;
            cout<<"Bob won: "<<bCount<<" times"<<endl;
            cout<<"Charlie won: "<<cCount<<" times"<<endl;


}
```

Comment: do you have a question? something more specific?

Comment: It's the logic of the puzzle. Everyone shoots once (if they make it to their turn). If Aaron kills charlie then bob shoots at Aaron (noone shoots at bob). If Aaron fails to kill charlie then bob shoots at charlie (bob is still alive). If Bob fails to kill charlie, charlie kills bob (Charlie is still alive). Therefore Aaron can never win. (At least 1 other person is alive if Aaron is alive).

Comment: Why is Aaron getting 0 wins at the end of the program? I believe it is because a random number isn't generated each shot, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @TimothyMurphy so do you believe I should put a conditional statement in for aaron to re-shoot at Charlie if they are both still alive?

Comment: I missed, some of you're code the first read through. The main problem is you need to generate a new random value for each shot. They're independent events (as long as they make it to their turn). You should make it so it repeats until only one person stands.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Please follow the steps at http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans to get yourself unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

It's how you're performing your randomness. Really each person should get their own "dice roll" to see if they shoot.

So instead, I would suggest changing start to something like the following:

```
void start(int& aCount, int& bCount, int& dCount){
  if (rand()%101 <= aShot){ // Aaron Shoots Charlie
    while (true) { // Continue until winner
      if (rand()%101 <= bShot){ // Bob Shoots Aaron and wins.
        ++bCount; return;
      } else if (rand()%101 <= aShot){ // Aaron Shoots at Bob and wins.
        ++aCount; return;
      } 
    }
  } else if (rand()%101 <= bShot){ // Bob Shoots at Charlie -- Charlie dies
    while (true){ // continue until winner.
      if (rand()%101 <= aShot){ // Aaron kills Bob and wins
        ++aCount; return;
      }
      if (rand()%101 <= bShot){ // Bob kills Aaron and wins
        ++bCount; return;
      }
    }
  } else { // Charlie is alive and kills bob.
    if (rand()%101 <= aShot){ // Aaron kills Charlie and wins
      ++aCount;
    } else { // Aaron missed and looses to Charlie
      ++cCount;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code generates a new random number [0,100] for each shot (excluding Charlies, since he always wins). And continues until only one person is left. You're code always has Aaron loose since you use the same random value for each shot.

I.E. If Aaron originally missed, he would always miss and therefore lose. If Aaron originally hit Charlie, Bob would kill Aaron (Bob always hits if Aaron hit).

Answer (score 0):

The main logical flaw is that you assign a value to **result** before calling the `start`.

The only scenario where Aaron can win is when `result <= 30`, in which case he kills Charlie, but then it is also true that `result <= 50` which guarantees Bob will shoot Aaron.

What I would do is assign a random number to result before each "shot". simplified that would look like:

```
int alive = 2; //makes counter
while (alive){  //a better way to loop
    if(aAlive){
        if (cAlive){
            // Aaron Shoots at Charlie
            result = rand()%101;
            if (aShot >= result) {
                cAlive=false;
                alive--;}
        }
        else{
            //Aaron shoots at Bob
            result = rand()%101;
            if (aShot >= result) {
                bAlive=false;
                alive--;}
        }
    }

    if (bAlive){
        if (cAlive){
            //Bob shoots at Charlie
            result = rand()%101;
                if (bShot >= result) {
                    cAlive=false; 
                    alive--;
                }
        }
        else {
            //Bob shoots at Aaron
            result = rand()%101;
            if (bShot >= result) {
                aAlive=false;
                alive--;
            }
        }
    }

    if (cAlive){
        if (bAlive){
            //Charlie shoots at Bob
            result = rand()%101;
            if (cShot >= result){
                bAlive=false;
                alive--;
            }
        }
        else{
            //Charlie shoots at Aaron;
            result = rand()%101;
            if (cShot >= result){
                aAlive=false;
                alive--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```